# LocalServer - 2/3 services Running WAMP - MySQL is not Running [FIXED]

Tags: mysql, wamp

I recently ran into a problem that mysqld service wasn't running.

I checked the MySQL's wamp log and got the following messages:

> [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
> [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?

So I ran it and realized that my TCP port 3306 was already running with another mysqld.exe process

```
netstat -ano|find "3306"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4576
  TCP    0.0.0.0:33060          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4576
  TCP    [::]:3306              [::]:0                 LISTENING       4576
  TCP    [::]:33060             [::]:0                 LISTENING       4576
```

after that I went to Task Manager and found the 4576 PID which was the other mysqld.exe running. So I finished the task and restarted my WAMP server, and all services went smoothly.

The problem probably occurred because I've got two wamp servers installed, don't ask me why... Hope I can help someone with this same problem.

Comment: How can I put this as solved? I'm new at Stackoverflow

Comment: [edit] the question and remove the solution part and then post an answer to the question.